# Как выбрать по столбцу только по первым двум цифрам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть DataFrame, в котором `Инн` является индексом (int).
Таблица выглядит следующим образом:

```
Инн        Название       Тип
231216     Орк            есть
432569     Шрек           нет
```

Подскажите, как сделать выборку по столбцу `Инн` по первым двум цифрам (остальные цифры не имеют значение)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение *без преобразования столбца `Инн` в строки*:

```
In [34]: mask = (df["Инн"] // 10**(np.ceil(np.log10(df["Инн"])).astype(int)-2)).isin(search_items)

In [35]: df[mask]
Out[35]:
      Инн Название  Тип
1  432569     Шрек  нет
```

---

пошагово:

находим число разрядов числа:

```
In [37]: np.ceil(np.log10(df["Инн"])).astype(int)
Out[37]:
0    6
1    6
Name: Инн, dtype: int32
```

возводим 10 в степень `(число разрядов минус 2)`:

```
In [38]: 10**(np.ceil(np.log10(df["Инн"])).astype(int)-2)
Out[38]:
0    10000
1    10000
Name: Инн, dtype: int32
```

делим (целочисленно) исходный ряд чисел на получившийся на предыдущем шаге результат:

```
In [39]: (df["Инн"] // 10**(np.ceil(np.log10(df["Инн"])).astype(int)-2))
Out[39]:
0    23
1    43
Name: Инн, dtype: int64
```

...

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
search_items = [42, 43, 44]

res = df[df["Инн"].astype(str).str[:2].astype("int8").isin(search_items)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [22]: res
Out[22]:
      Инн Название  Тип
1  432569     Шрек  нет
```

Comment: Прошу прощения. Ввожу код. Ошибку выдает.
'''
df = pd.read_excel('rez.xlsx', header=0, index_col="Инн")
search_items = [42, 43, 44]

res = df[df["Инн"].astype(str).str[:2].astype("int8").isin(search_items)]
KeyError: 'Инн'
 '''
Написание проверил.

Comment: @VladVladov, уберите параметр `index_col="Инн"`. Решение исходит из того, что `"Инн"` - обычный столбец

Comment: Я тогда новый вопрос размещу. С типом данных ошибся. Спасибо за ответ.