# Выбрать по столбцу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

Есть DataFrame. Таблица выглядит следующим образом:

```
Инн        Название       Тип
231216     Орк            есть
432569     Шрек           нет

df.dtypes
Инн  object
```

Подскажите, как сделать выборку по столбцу Инн по первым двум цифрам (остальные цифры не имеют значение)?

Comment: а [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158281/211923) разве не работает?

Comment: При первом решении пишет следующее: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ГР'

Comment: В первом варианте Инн - int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
      Инн Название   Тип
0  231216      Орк  есть
1  432569     Шрек   нет
2      ГР       ГР    ГР

In [98]: df.dtypes
Out[98]:
Инн         object
Название    object
Тип         object
dtype: object
```

решение:

```
search_items = ["42", "43", "44"]
res = df[df["Инн"].str[:2].isin(search_items)]
```

результат:

```
In [101]: res
Out[101]:
      Инн Название  Тип
1  432569     Шрек  нет
```

Comment: У меня такую же ошибку пишет ( : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ГР'

Comment: @VladVladov, исправил ответ. Обратите внимание на то, что в `search_items` теперь используются строки вместо чисел

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @MaxU Так в чём разница от первого вопроса ТС? Помоему, надо более конкретно упомянуть об отличиях в ответе.

Comment: @0xdb, разница в том, что у автора в столбце `Инн` встречаются нечисловые строки - такие как `"ГР"`. Я об этом не знал отвечая на предыдущий вопрос...